# Cordova loading local images from CSS

Tags: ios, css, angularjs, cordova, iframe

I've a Cordova 5+ application built with Ionic 1 and Angular 1.
I use ViewerJS to load and read PDF files (retrieved from a remote server): I used an iframe making it working.
On desktop browsers, like Chrome, it works perfectly while on Cordova (precisely, on iOS with WKWebView) it throws errors like:

> Not allowed to load local resource file://

First of all, those images are loaded from a CSS file (I'm expected that it uses HTTP instead of file protocol):

> url(/images/image.png)

Second, this is the signature of the iframe:

```
<iframe class="row" sandbox="allow-scripts" ng-src="{{::viewerJsUrl}}"></iframe>
```

Third and last: I've followed this entire guide, tuning the Cordova build as fine as possible -> https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md

What am I missing?
Is there a security problem with iframe on Cordova (iOS, using WKWebView)?

Comment: Did you try adding a CSP to your HTML?  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';` or read more at https://content-security-policy.com/" />`

Comment: @daan.desmedt sure, as mentioned in this guide -> https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md